# Why don't `OnErrorNotImplementedException` occurs in `onComplete` and `onNext`?

Tags: java, rx-java2

I encountered to `OnErrorNotImplementedException` when I'm learning RxJava2. I learned that this exception occur due to isn't implemented error handler to subscriber. So, I thought why don't it exist except `onError` method. Why?

Comment: One may not care about items or completion being ignored, but ignoring an error is something that should be explicitly handled (or ignored).

Comment: It only handle (or ignore) error, mean that `onComplete` and `onNext` need not especially to handle?

Comment: @紫陽花 pls check my answer.

Comment: I had forgot to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doOnError` method doesn't consume the error and eventually it will be thrown in subscriber. In this case if you are not handling in subscriber then `OnErrorNotImplementedException` will be thrown.

below approaches will consume error as mentioned in `subscribe` method.

> Approach 1:

```
Observable.just(new Object())
            .doOnNext(o -> { /* /* This method catches the on next but doesn't consume it. */})
            .doOnComplete(() -> { /* test */})
            .doOnError(throwable -> {/* This method catches the error but doesn't consume it. */})
            .subscribe(o ->
                    {/* success */}
                    ,
                    throwable -> {/* error */} // here error will be consumed at the end
            );
```

> Approach 2:

```
Observable.just(new Object())
            .doOnNext(o -> { /* /* This method catches the on next but doesn't consume it. */})
            .doOnComplete(() -> { /* test */})
            .doOnError(throwable -> {/* This method catches the error but doesn't consume it. */})
            .subscribe(
                    new DefaultObserver<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Object o) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                          // here error will be consumed at the end
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    }
            );
```

Overall, You have to consume error otherwise you will face the same error which you've mentioned.